# SQL query error 10002 - Hive query

Tags: sql, hiveql

I am trying to execute below query, but it gives an error always.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DAILY_STORE_ACTIVITY_HADOOP;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE DAILY_STORE_ACTIVITY_HADOOP (storeActivityId String, storeId string, associateProgramId string, earningsDate bigint, totalHappyBonus double, totalNonHappyShippedEarning double, totalShippedEarnings double, totalReturnedEarnings double, totalNewCustomerBonus double, totalNonHappyRefundEarning double, totalKindleEbooksCount BIGINT,  totalFreeKindleEbooksCount BIGINT, totalCount BIGINT) ROW FORMAT delimited fields terminated by '\n';
ALTER TABLE DAILY_STORE_ACTIVITY_HADOOP set SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe';
ALTER TABLE DAILY_STORE_ACTIVITY_HADOOP set location 'hdfs://${processingOutputLocation}';

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE DAILY_STORE_ACTIVITY_HADOOP select CONCAT((t.storeId),'||','${programIdString}')storeActivityId, 
t.storeId storeId, 
'${programIdString}' associateProgramId, 
t.earningsDate earningsDate, 
t.totalHappyBonus totalHappyBonus, 
t.totalNonHappyShippedEarning totalNonHappyShippedEarning,
t.totalShippedEarnings totalShippedEarnings, 
t.totalReturnedEarnings totalReturnedEarnings, 
t.totalNewCustomerBonus totalNewCustomerBonus, 
t.totalNonHappyRefundEarning totalNonHappyRefundEarning, 
t.totalKindleEbooksCount totalKindleEbooksCount, 
t.totalFreeKindleEbooksCount totalFreeKindleEbooksCount, 
t.totalShippedQuantity totalShippedQuantity from (

SELECT 
store_id storeId, 
unix_timestamp(request_date ,'dd-MMM-yyyy') * 1000 earningsDate, 
0 as totalKindleEbooksCount,
0 as totalShippedQuantity,
0 as totalFreeKindleEbooksCount, 
sum(total_Happy_bonus) as totalHappyBonus,
sum(total_non_Happy_shipped_earning) as totalNonHappyShippedEarning,
sum(total_shipped_earnings) as totalShippedEarnings, 
sum(total_returned_earnings) as totalReturnedEarnings,
sum(total_new_customer_bonus) as totalNewCustomerBonus,
sum(total_non_Happy_refund_earning) as totalNonHappyRefundEarning

from STORE_ACTIVITY_AGGREGATES where associate_program_id=${programId} and
unix_timestamp(request_date, 'dd-MMM-yyyy') >= unix_timestamp('${startDate}', 'dd-MMM-yyyy') and
unix_timestamp(request_date, 'dd-MMM-yyyy') < unix_timestamp('${endDate}', 'dd-MMM-yyyy') group by store_id,
unix_timestamp(request_date,'dd-MMM-yyyy') having sum(total_Happy_bonus) <> 0 or sum(total_non_Happy_shipped_earning) <> 0
or sum(total_shipped_earnings) <> 0 or sum(total_returned_earnings) <> 0 or sum(total_new_customer_bonus) <> 0 or
sum(total_non_Happy_refund_earning) <> 0
) t GROUP BY t.STOREID, t.earningsDate;
```

The `ERROR` which I am facing is a `FAILED: SemanticException`

> [Error 10002]: Line 7:2 Invalid column reference 'totalHappyBonus'.

I need an expert's help to rectify this error.

Comment: And what about the error message do you not get?  There is no column with that name in the referenced table.

Comment: But here totalHappyBonus column is just an alias, then why it needs to be in the referenced table?